# How to evaluate $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\arctan x - \arcsin x}{\tan x - \sin x}$

Tags: calculus

I have a stuck on the problem of L'Hospital's Rule,

$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\arctan x - \arcsin x}{\tan x - \sin x}$ which is in I.F. $\frac{0}{0}$

If we use the rule, we will have

$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{1+x^2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}{\sec^2x-\cos x}$.

So, I think that I approach this problem in the wrong way.

Have you guy any idea?

Comment: Use his rule again

Comment: @AaronM I think the denominator becomes 0 again when $x\to 0$

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, one may use standard [Taylor expansions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Definition), as $x \to 0$,
$$
\begin{align}
\sin x&=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^4)
\\\tan x&=x+\frac{x^3}{3}+o(x^4)
\\\arctan x&=x-\frac{x^3}{3}+o(x^4)
\\\arcsin x&=x+\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^4)
\end{align}
$$ giving, as $x \to 0$,
$$ \frac{\arctan x - \arcsin x}{\tan x - \sin x}= \frac{-\frac{x^3}{2}+o(x^4)}{\frac{x^3}{2}+o(x^4)}=-1+o(x) \to -1.
$$

Comment: Thank you @olivier.  I think about Taylor's too, but it has a bit difficult to understand, for example, the little o.

Comment: @AuthawichNarissayaporn You are welcome. We say that $f(x)$ is equal to $o(x^4)$ if $\frac{f(x)}{x^4} \to 0$ as $x \to 0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. At first, I have a little confusion that in some books, $f(x)\in o(g(x))$ means $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$. Now, I understood. :D

Comment: @AuthawichNarissayaporn Yes, here we are looking at what's going on as $x \to 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\arcsin x = t$ so that $\sin t = x$ and $$\tan t = \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1 - x^{2}}}$$ so that $$\arcsin x = t = \arctan\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1 - x^{2}}}$$ and then we can proceed as follows
\begin{align}
L &= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\arctan x - \arcsin x}{\tan x - \sin x}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\arctan x - \arcsin x}{\sin x(1 - \cos x)}\cdot\cos x\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\arctan x - \arcsin x}{\sin x(1 - \cos x)}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\arctan x - \arcsin x}{\sin^{3}x}\cdot(1 + \cos x)\notag\\
&= 2\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\arctan x - \arcsin x}{x^{3}}\cdot\frac{x^{3}}{\sin^{3}x}\notag\\
&= 2\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\arctan x - \arctan \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1 - x^{2}}}}{x^{3}}\notag\\
&= 2\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\arctan \left(\dfrac{x - \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1 - x^{2}}}}{1 + \dfrac{x^{2}}{\sqrt{1 - x^{2}}}}\right)}{x^{3}}\notag\\
&= 2\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\arctan \left(\dfrac{x(\sqrt{1 - x^{2}} - 1)}{\sqrt{1 - x^{2}} + x^{2}}\right)}{\dfrac{x(\sqrt{1 - x^{2}} - 1)}{\sqrt{1 - x^{2}} + x^{2}}}\cdot\dfrac{\dfrac{x(\sqrt{1 - x^{2}} - 1)}{\sqrt{1 - x^{2}} + x^{2}}}{x^{3}}\notag\\
&= 2\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sqrt{1 - x^{2}} - 1}{x^{2}(\sqrt{1 - x^{2}} + x^{2})}\notag\\
&= 2\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sqrt{1 - x^{2}} - 1}{x^{2}}\notag\\
&= 2\lim_{x \to 0}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - x^{2}} + 1}\notag\\
&= -2\cdot\frac{1}{2}\notag\\
&= -1\notag
\end{align}
In the above we have used the standard limits $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1 = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\arctan x}{x}$$ There is no need to use advanced tools like Taylor's series and L'Hospital's Rule.

Comment: If this problem is found in the section of Non-L'hospital, this way will be the best. Thanks.

Comment: @AuthawichNarissayaporn: Well, other people here have given reasonably good answers using L'Hospital or Taylor so I though to add a different and simpler approach. BTW when one is learning calculus, it is best to avoid the technique of L'Hospital's Rule because it severely hampers concept building (the technique is best suited for time constrained competitive exams and even then Taylor series approach beats it by a wide margin).

Answer (score 0):

Hint:use the L'Hospital's Rule three times
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{(\arctan x - \arcsin x)'''}{(\tan x - \sin x)'''}$$

Comment: I will try, but I think that it may be complicated.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is OK, but you should try and simplify things before going on.

The numerator is
$$
\frac{1}{1+x^2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=
\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}-1-x^2}{(1+x^2)\sqrt{1-x^2}}=
\frac{-x^2(3+x^2)}{(1+x^2)\sqrt{1-x^2}(\sqrt{1-x^2}+1+x^2)}
$$
The denominator is
$$
\frac{1}{\cos^2x}-\cos x=\frac{1-\cos^3x}{\cos^2x}=
\frac{(1-\cos x)(1+\cos x+\cos^2x)}{\cos^2x}
$$
so you can rewrite your limit as
$$
\lim_{x\to0}
\frac{x^2}{1-\cos x}
\frac{-(3+x^2)\cos^2x}{(1+x^2)\sqrt{1-x^2}(\sqrt{1-x^2}+1+x^2)(1+\cos x+\cos^2x)}
$$
which is easy to compute (the second fraction is not “indeterminate”).

Of course, Taylor expansion is easier.

Comment: Oh I see. It's just a simplification. Thanks a lot.